# How to append DDL during AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to alter the value of a drop down list whenever the partial view is called. At the moment the AJAX call retrieves the information i need, but the user has to alter the location value in the partial view before saving, basically i want the value of location to be changed during the ajax call, thus saving the user time on altering the value by hand, i've attempted it but clearly doesn't work (see the code below), any ideas on where im going wrong?

_CameraInfo.cshtml (partial view)

```
@model JobTracker.Models.Job


<h2>Edit and Confirm</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Job</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JobID)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderID)

  <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationID, "Location")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("LocationID", null, new {id ="Location" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationID)
    </div><br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HighPriority)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HighPriority, new SelectList(
    new[] 
    { 
        new { Value = "Yes", Text = "Yes" },
        new { Value = "No", Text = "No" },
    },
     "Value",
     "Text",
    Model
))

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HighPriority)
    </div><br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments)
    </div><br />

      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new SelectList(
    new[] 
    { 
        new { Value = "In Progress", Text = "In Progress" },
        new { Value = "Completed", Text = "Completed" },
        new { Value = "Not Started", Text = "Not Started" },
        new { Value = "Stopped", Text = "Stopped" },
    },
     "Value",
     "Text",
    Model
))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status)
    </div><br />

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>

}
```

AJAX call

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qr-number').on('change', function () {
        var ddl = $('#Location');
        var value = "cleanroom";
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: '/CameraInfo/Edit',
            data: { ID: $('#qr-number').val() },
            success: function (response) {
                ddl.append(value);
                $('#Sample').html(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText != "") {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                    alert("Some thing wrong..");
                }
            }
        });
    });
    });
});
```

The DDL is populated by the model data by the way.

Please let me know if you require any further information :)

Comment: Not clear what your asking. Are you wanting a particular option to be selected in the dropdownlist for `LocationID`?

Comment: yes, i want a particular option to be selected on once the partial view renders to the user

Comment: Whats `$('#qr-number')`? Whats `$('#Sample')`? If the value of property `LocationID` matches the value of one of the options then that option will be selected. But there is so much odd code its hard to understand this. For example it should be just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HighPriority, new SelectList(new List<string>() { "Yes", "No" })`

Comment: $('#qr-number') is the JobID parsed from the scanned QR code and $('#Sample') is where the partial view is loaded from the AJAX call

Comment: But does that partial view exist when your first run this ajax code? If not then `var ddl = $('#Location');` would be undefined. Even if it did exist, what are you trying to do with `var value = "cleanroom";` and `ddl.append(value);`?

Comment: it does exist, the var value and ddl.append was my attempt at altering the DDL value

Comment: If the dropdown includes a option with the value "cleanroom", then to select it using javascript it would be `ddl.val('cleanroom')` but your view has `@Html.DropDownList("LocationID", null, ..)` which indicates you have other errors as well, so I'm not really sure what your doing

Comment: the locationID, null is needed in order to alter the text, it works fine for changing the values to the database

Comment: the dropdownlist is binded in the controller, the "LocationID" is the binder from the controller

Comment: Resolved using the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523943/ddl-fails-to-change-during-ajax-call-mvc?noredirect=1#comment47203984_29523943

Answer (score 0):

`for ddl value`
`ddl.val(value);`
`for ddl text`
`ddl.text(value);`
use `.val()` or `.text()` not `.append()`

Comment: i've altered it to try .val() and .text() the value still doesnt change :/